# Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route Symfony2

Tags: symfony

My security.yml

```
firewalls:
    user_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: chain_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login_action
            check_path: login_check
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            default_target_path: user_show_redirect
        logout:
            path: logout_action
            target: /login
```

I whant after login redirect user to his profile, but i don't know how create the controller. Now, my controller look like

```
 /**
 * @Route("/user/show", name="user_show_redirect")
 * @return array
 */
public function redirectAction($id)
{
    return array('user' => $this->getUser());
}
```

I can not figure out how to do the right thing and easy. Please, reply

Comment: Try to get the current user in the controller, not in the URL parameter, by using [`getUser()`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object).

Comment: can you write me a little example...

Comment: I misread the question, the problem is with `id`, not with `getUser()`.

Comment: Please avoid editing your question to remove the original problem, the content is now inconsistent with the title.

Comment: Add the new error messages at the end of your question, don't alter the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$id` parameter is not used in your function, you can remove it:

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/show", name="user_show_redirect")
 * @return array
 */
public function redirectAction()
{
    return array('user' => $this->getUser());
}
```

And the controller needs to return a Response, render a Twig template or use the [`@Template` annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html):

Example with [`render()`ing of a Twig template](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#controller-rendering-templates):

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/show", name="user_show_redirect")
 * @return array
 */
public function redirectAction()
{
    return $this->render(
        'AcmeWebsiteBundle:Default:profile.html.twig',
        array('user' => $this->getUser())
    );
}
```

You have to create a file in <kbd>src/Acme/WebsiteBundle/Resources/views/Default/profile.html.twig</kbd> with the following content:

```
{{ user.firstName }}
```

It implies that your `User` entity has a `getFirstName()` method, it will display the first name of the user.

See the [Symfony2 official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html) for template inheritance and more.

Comment: i get error `The controller must return a response (Array(user => Object(Qualium\ModelBundle\Entity\User)) given).`